# How to detect the album arts which are not embedded into audio files in WinRT C#?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, media, albumart

There are libraries like taglib# to detect embedded album arts in audio files. But how to detect the art if it's not embedded? It's there in the same folder where the audio file is and named like "AlbumArt_{6CF60723-E19A-4DA9-B4AC-FAB809BC8D4A}_Large.jpg". Is there a way to connect the appropriate audio file & the image? How does the Media Player or the Windows Phone Music app reads it? There should be a some sort of a connection between the file & the image name but I'm unable to find it until now. There's no GUID property in the audio file as well. Anyone?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Those "AlbumArt_{GUID}_Large.jpg" files are created by Media Player and Windows itself, there's a media library that contains the mapping between files and AlbumArts, but as far as I know, you cannot get access to this mapping.